# Force A5 Paper-size in Chrome's print settings CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've to print out 2 html pages in a web-app.
The first page must be printed out in **A5** size , 
the second in **A4** size.
I tried to force the a5 print settings with

```
@media print{
    @page {
        size: a5 landscape;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

and the a4 print settings in the other file with

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: a4;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

A4 is working fine,
but if I try to print the A5 page , paper-size doesn't change
(but landscape mode is set)

Comment: Have you got this working in the end?

Comment: unfortunately i'm still searching for a solution for this :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could uset paper-css library as it will help you easily define the paper size 
by paper-css lib 
load the css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper-css/0.3.0/paper.css">
```

then set the style in the `<head>` part

```
<style>@page { size: A5 }</style>
```

then set the body class to `A5` like the following

```
<!-- Set "A5", "A4" or "A3" for class name -->
<!-- Set also "landscape" if you need -->
<body class="A5">

  <!-- Each sheet element should have the class "sheet" -->
  <!-- "padding-**mm" is optional: you can set 10, 15, 20 or 25 -->
  <section class="sheet padding-10mm">

    <!-- Write HTML just like a web page -->
    <article>This is an A5 document.</article>

  </section>

</body>
```

for more information follow the link below
https://github.com/cognitom/paper-css

Answer (score 1):

Using this media query content will adjust for `A5`.

```
@media print
{
    @page
    {
         size: 8.5in 11in; 
    }
}
```