# Setting paper size to A5 using css not working in google chrome page print

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to print the webpage in A5 using chrome's default print page dialog box. I managed to write some css but paper size still remains A4 in chrome's print dialog box and large margin appears on the page.

I have tried setting css rules like setting margin of page to 0 but didn't work.

`@page{margin: 0; size: A5 portrait;}`

The paper size in chrome's print dialog box should be selected to A5 and there should not be any margin in the page

Answer (score 1):

Could use the paper css library as stated in : 
[stackoverflow force a5 paper size in chrome print settings css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064707/force-a5-paper-size-in-chromes-print-settings-css)
also some valuable read that might help
[w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/page.html) or [stackoverflow disabling browser print options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page/2780518#2780518)

Comment: That only works for viewing in browser. But when going to print dialog box using ctrl+p shows the same problem as i stated. Paper size is still set to A4.

Comment: Was anyone able to resolve this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `size` CSS property is still experimental and does not have much support yet, and so should not be relied on.

You can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size

Comment: Is there any javascript/jquery plugin that i can use instead to achieve a5 paper size?